# Why is the termination behaviour of vscode different with other GUI program (WinMerge) when invoking from PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, powershell-5.1

In Windows PowerShell 5.1, after run `& code .`, a VSCode window opens, and the control returns back to PowerShell immediately. After the PowerShell exists, the VSCode will not be terminated.

On the other hand, when invoke other external program, such as WinMerge, after run `& WinMergeU`, a WinMerge window opens, and the control does not return back to PowerShell until WinMerge window is closed. And If PowerShell exists, WinMerge will be terminated.

Why the behaviour is different?

Comment: It depends if the method you are calling is blocking (synchronous) or non blocking (asynchronous).  You can't make synchronous code run as a background method unless you wrap the synchronous code with a asynchronous method.  In either of your sample code, the code doesn't continue until the method you are calling returns.

Comment: `& code <folder1> ; & code <folder2>` opens two VSCode Window and PowerShell can continue run other command. `& WinMergeU ; & WinMergeU` open first WinMerge window and PowerShell continue waits its terminatation. After close the first WinMerge window, an second winodw opened and PowerShell is still waiting. The calling method is the same (`&`), so I think it depends on the called program. But I do not how these two programs are different.

Comment: That is what I said.  One is blocking and the other is not blocking.

Answer (score 0):

the difference is what is actuall happening:

when you run the command `code`, you are not really running `code.exe`. its starting a cmd script that spawns a new `code.exe` process with whatever arguments you passed it.
to see what a command actually executes, use the command `get-command 'yourcommand'`, or with code `get-command code`.
this will show the follwing source: `C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin\code.cmd`.

Opening up this will show you:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set VSCODE_DEV=
set ELECTRON_RUN_AS_NODE=1
"%~dp0..\Code.exe" "%~dp0..\resources\app\out\cli.js" --ms-enable-electron-run-as-node %*
endlocal
```

so this means that in both cases you are waiting for execution to end, but for code its a `code.cmd` script and not actually `code.exe`.

If you want to start new processes and don't wait for them, you can use the command `start-process winmergeu`